# Prevent concurrent usage and deallocation

Tags: c++, concurrency

Given the following C-API internally implemented in C++

```
struct OpaqueObject;

struct OpaqueObject *allocateObject();
int deallocateObject(struct OpaqueObject *obj);

int useObject(struct OpaqueObject *obj);
```

It is safe to allocate, use and deallocate several distinct `struct OpaqueObject`-Instances concurrently. Of course, the concurrent usage of one `struct OpaqueObject`-Instance is not allowed and would yield undefined behavior. As a safeguard, the `struct OpaqueObject` contains a mutex, prohibiting exactly this situation: The function `useObject()` returns with an error code, if several threads try to call it with the same `struct OpaqueObject`-Instance.

```
struct OpaqueObject {
    std::mutex access;
    // ...
};

int useObject(struct OpaqueObject *obj) {
    if (!obj->access.try_lock()) {
        // different thread currently uses this obj
        return CONCURRENT_USE_ERROR;
    } else {
        // start using this obj
        // ...
        obj->access.unlock();
        return OK;
    }
}
```

But how can this safeguard mechanism extended to the function `deallocateObject()`? The first naive approach would be

```
int deallocateObject(struct OpaqueObject *obj) {
    if (!obj->access.try_lock()) {
        // different thread currently uses this obj
        return CONCURRENT_USE_ERROR;
    } else {
        delete obj; // <--- (1)
        return OK;
    }
}
```

But it's undefined behavior to destroy a mutex when it's still locked. We can't simply unlock it right before line `(1)`, since this would completely foil our efforts to prevent concurrent usage and deallocation.

Is it possible to return with an error in either `useObject()` or `deallocateObject()`, if these functions were used concurrently with the same `struct OpaqueObject`-Instance?

Comment: Apart from the concurrency issue, this seems a bit dangerous because after you delete the object, other threads would still have a pointer to a deleted object.  One way you could get around it is to use std::shared_ptr to the object and a void* in the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exchange the `std::mutex` with a `std::atomic<int>`:

```
struct OpaqueObject {
    std::atomic<int> access = 0;
    // ...
};
```

And then in your functions you could atomically exchange the values and see if it is in use:

```
int useObject(struct OpaqueObject *obj) {
    if (obj->access.exchange(1)) {
        // different thread currently uses this obj
        return CONCURRENT_USE_ERROR;
    } else {
        // start using this obj
        // ...
        obj->access.exchange(0);
        return OK;
    }
}
```

If the object is in use variable `access` = 1 and `std::atomic::exchange` will return 1. Otherwise it returns 0 and sets `access` to 1.

Also deleting the object would work.

```
int deallocateObject(struct OpaqueObject *obj) {
    if (obj->access.exchange(1)) { // (*)
        // different thread currently uses this obj
        return CONCURRENT_USE_ERROR;
    } else {
        delete obj;                 // (**)
        return OK;
    }
}
```

**Important:** Have you considered what happen's after you have deleted the object? How do you notify other threads about it's deletion?

Comment: This sounds very promising and elegant! Above all, it relieves us from the burden to use a recursive mutex, too. Since there are also callbacks in our framework, we needed a recursive mutex to gracefully refuse reentrance from such a callback.

Comment: Of course, use-after-free is still undefined behavior and effectively there is only a very small section between `(*)` and `(**)` without it. The whole thing is a kind of precaution measure since we have to expect some misuse of our API and need at least some feedback to help our customers.

Comment: @phlipsy Glad you like it. Btw: I just found an error in my code (just in case you haven't notice already :) ): I forgot to remove the negation operator in the `if` clause of the `exchange`-operation after copying the code from your question. Now it should be correct in the answer: If `obj->access.exchange(1)` returns 1 the object is being accessed and the functions return `CONCURRENT_USE_ERROR`.

Comment: So, there are actually 2 problems you have to fiddle with: 1. Synchronize access to the object over several threads. 2. Deal with several references /pointers to one single object where the object might be destroyed. Solution for the 1st problem is given in the answer above. The 2nd one is not specific to threads. One possible solution would be to introduce some kind of garbage collection (ref counting with the counter having to be protected by a mutex?)? Should be not too hard to implement with c++since you can overload pretty much anything, starting with the assignment operator...?